# Can I install & licence Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB on a 'Stand-Alone' Machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, license

We currently ship custom machines for use in industrial control, they run Windows 7 with a shell replacement. They are connected to a network, but not a member of a domain and in normal use do not have an internet connection (however this can't be relied upon). Automatic Updates are disabled via Local GPO.

At the moment, we have a tested WIM image updated every few months with the latest Security Updates from MS. This is used to build new machines.

To achieve this with Windows 10, it looks like I need to use Enterprise LTSB, which requires a Volume Licence Agreement:

**Does Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB need to see a Volume Licencing Server in order for it's licence to remain valid?**

**These devices are sold to the client, how do we transfer the licence to them? Do we get a COA per licence?**

**Are there any other editions of Windows 10 which I can use to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows 10 IoT Enterprise, which is basically Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB but with a different license and with the addition of embedded functionality which would probably be useful for your intended use. This version has different license terms and is often cheaper due to its multiple license tiers (tablet, i5, i7, etc).